# React Router 4: Different templates from root route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have been experimenting with react router 4 on a new project and one small issue I had come across is how to make sure "sub" routes don't inherit from parent routes.

Say I have a page at the root route `/` which renders navigation and dashboard, and '/profile' that displays users profile, sharing templates with the root route, but I want to redirect users to `/login` if they are not logged in, with the structure of RR4 the templates from the root route will reflect on the login child route, I have though of several ways to get ride of this behaviour but they all seem hacky, one of the ways I thought of is using RegEx.

Not sure what the best approach should be..

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route path='/' component={() => <h1>Home Page</h1> }/>
        <Route path='/login' component={ () => <h1>Logins</h1>  }/>
        <Route path='/profile' component={ () => <h1>Profile</h1>  }/>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Both Logins and Profile display `Home Page`, but I only want Profile to do that.

Comment: Could you include some code, specifically the routes you've configured?

Comment: Can you show how your child routes are " sharing templates with the root route,"?

Comment: @MattD Please find updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Switch` in your App component as follows

```
<Router>
    <div>
       <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={<HomeTemplate/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' component={ () => <h1>Logins</h1>  }/>           
       </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Create a `HomeTempate` component and add a `Switch` with all `Route` s that need to derive the template.

```
<Header/>
<TemplateSpecificComponents/>
<Switch>
      <Route path='/profile' render={ () =><h1>Profile</h1> }/>
      ...
</Switch>
```

From the React Router documentation (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) :

> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

Edit : Updated to render HomeTemplate in Profile but not in Login.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the templates is now not shared with profile page, I still want to partially maintain the template sharing property while preventing it from sharing with a few pages

Answer (score 0):

One way I had thought of fixing this problem is by using a HOC. For instance

```
let template = function(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
         <h1>Home Page</h1>
         <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
      )
    }
  }
}

<Router>
    <div>
       <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={ template() } exact/>
        <Route path='/login' component={ () => <h1>Logins</h1>  }/>
        <Route path='/profile' render={ template(<h1>Profile</h1> ) }/>
       </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```